# How to block XML-RPC attack?

Tags: plugins, xml, xml-rpc

Using Apache Web Server
For blocking xmlrpc, adding this code into .htaccess file

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

But while adding this The domain being Unreachable. What should do...

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'order' order. I do it this way:

```
# Block WordPress xmlrpc.php requests
<Files xmlrpc.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
# allow from xx.xx.xx.xx   #add allowed IP addresses
</Files>
```

And, to ensure it's blocked, I add this to the functions.php file.

```
add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');
```

Actually, I put the above command and others into a private plugin, so I don't have to worry about Child Themes, or theme changes.

(Side note: I had a WP site compromised via an xmlrpc attack.)